# Delete rows in Memcached based on date

Tags: perl, caching, garbage-collection, memcached

Hello I am implementing simple garbage collector over memcached in Perl.
And i want to delete all rows (key, value is serialized(payload, date)) before or after date.

What is the best effective implementation? Get all data and then check the date in for cycle(But the data could get very big and i think it could be slow and not very effective)?

Any other ideas or opinions?

Thanks, Cospel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot iterate memcached keys in a effective way(i mean there is no "good" way to do that). Best solution is to setup proper **expires** field, so entries will be expired/deleted automatically. Also its good to remove the key right after the moment it is no longer needed.

Internally memcached uses LRU, so when no memory available, most unused items will be discarded. This can be entries with big TTL (expire time), so probably its a parameter to tune for your needs.